# QJsonValue is private?

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning C++ and trying to make something. But I ran into an error and I am not sure what's up. I am trying to create a simple thing that would accept an array, and turn it into JSON. But I'm getting an error

```
'QJsonValue::QJsonValue(const void*)' is private
within this context
```

file

```
#include "LoginDialog.h"
#include "ui_LoginDialog.h"

LoginDialog::LoginDialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::LoginDialog)
{
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

LoginDialog::~LoginDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void LoginDialog::set_socket(Socket *socket)
{
    socket = socket;

    QJsonArray data;
    data.prepend("Hello");

    socket->sendData(data);
}

void LoginDialog::on_minimize_clicked()
{
    setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized);
}

void LoginDialog::on_quit_clicked()
{
    exit(1);
}
```

accepting function

```
void Socket::sendData(QJsonArray data)
{
    qDebug() << data[1];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is here:

`data.prepend("Hello");`

The `prepend` member function takes in a `QJsonValue`, which happens to have many constructors.  Passing in a `const char*` makes it ambiguous as to which one you are referring to.  C++ compilers will resolve this to a `bool` before they would resolve it to a `QString`.  To combat this, the author of `QJsonValue` did this:

```
private:
    // avoid implicit conversions from char* to bool
    inline QJsonValue(const void*) {}
```

In any event, you can fix this problem by being more explicit:

```
data.prepend(QStringLiteral("Hello")); // Qt 5
data.prepend(QLatin1String("Hello")); // Qt 4, Latin1 string
data.prepend(QString("Hello")); // Qt 4, non-Latin1 string
```

Look [here](http://woboq.com/blog/qstringliteral.html) for more information about `QStringLiteral`.